# ContextMenu in a ListView/GridView

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, gridview, contextmenu

Inside a ListView, I have a GridView and am trying to set things up so that when the user right clicks a 'row' in the ListView, I'm able to access the original data object.
I think its the gridview part of the ListView that is making this a bit more difficult.

I've created a sample that demonstrates where I'm having difficulties. When the user right clicks the row eg Person1, I'd like to able to access the PersonClass data object in the MenuItem_Click handler. I've tried playing with PlacementTarget but all I get is null objects or objects of type MenuItem.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>        
        <ContextMenu Name="cm" x:Key="TestContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Context1" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Context2"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Context3"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="20" Name="TestListView" SelectionMode="Multiple">

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TestContextMenu}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FirstName" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Surname}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Code:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

        Dim Person1 As New PersonClass("John", "Fletcher")
        Dim Person2 As New PersonClass("Bob", "Smith")

        Dim ListOfPersons As New List(Of PersonClass)
        ListOfPersons.Add(Person1)
        ListOfPersons.Add(Person2)

        TestListView.ItemsSource = ListOfPersons

    End Sub

    Private Sub MenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

        MsgBox(e.OriginalSource.ToString)
        MsgBox(sender.ToString)
        MsgBox(e.Source.ToString)


    End Sub

End Class


Public Class PersonClass

    Private _firstName As String
    Private _surname As String

    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _firstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _firstName = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Surname() As String
        Get
            Return _surname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _surname = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(FirstName As String, Surname As String)
        Me.FirstName = FirstName
        Me.Surname = Surname
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got PlacementTarget to work, here is the code below. The reason, selected item was no good, is if the item is already selected and your right click on it, the row gets unselected.

Change the Window.Resources from the inital post to:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu Name="cm" x:Key="TestContextMenu" >
        <MenuItem Header="Context1" Click="MenuItem_Click" >
            <MenuItem.DataContext>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}" Path="PlacementTarget.DataContext"/>
            </MenuItem.DataContext>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Context2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Context3"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

and

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

    Dim MenuI As New MenuItem
    MenuI = TryCast(sender, MenuItem)

    Dim APerson As New PersonClass
    APerson = MenuI.DataContext

    MsgBox(APerson.FirstName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, this simple code should do the trick (in the event MenuItem_Click). Also note that no explicit cast is needed as each item already represents a PersonClass instance:

```
If TestListView.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim person As PersonClass = TestListView.SelectedItem
    //Do something with "person"
Else
    MsgBox("No item selected!")
End If
```

Note that you have set the selection mode to multiple, with this code only the first item will be used in the code. For multiple items use this code :

```
If TestListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    For Each person As PersonClass In TestListView.SelectedItems
        //Do something with "person"
    Next
End If
```

Hope this helps!